# Import file to script and fill variables inside the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have script `import.sh`

```
. properties
sql=$(cat sql.sql)
${psql_path}/psql \
  -X \
  --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on \
  --set AUTOCOMMIT=on \
  --echo-all \
  ${sql}
  ${dbname} > ${log_file} 2>> ${log_file}
```

and file `properties`

```
psql_path="/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin"
dbname="postgres"
path="/opt/files"
log_file="ok.log"
```

and file `sql.sql`

```
  -c "truncate table SCHEMA.TABLE1;" \
  -c "\\copy SCHEMA.TABLE1 FROM '${path}/TABLE1.tsv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '\"'" \
  -c "truncate table SCHEMA.TABLE2;" \
  -c "\\copy SCHEMA.TABLE1 FROM '${path}/TABLE2.tsv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '\"'" \
```

i need to run `psql` command with importing lines from file `sql.sql` on the line `${sql}` in script `import.sh` but including text `/opt/files` instead of the variable itself `${path}`, eg:

```
${psql_path}/psql \
  -X \
  --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on \
  --set AUTOCOMMIT=on \
  --echo-all \
  -c "truncate table SCHEMA.TABLE1;" \
  -c "\\copy SCHEMA.TABLE1 FROM '/opt/files/TABLE1.tsv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '\"'" \
  -c "truncate table SCHEMA.TABLE2;" \
  -c "\\copy SCHEMA.TABLE2 FROM '/opt/files/TABLE2.tsv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '\"'" \
  ${dbname} > ${log_file} 2>> ${log_file}
```

edit: all im getting right now is example below. How do i insert the text of variable `${path}` ?

```
${psql_path}/psql \
  -X \
  --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on \
  --set AUTOCOMMIT=on \
  --echo-all \
  -c "truncate table SCHEMA.TABLE1;" \
  -c "\\copy SCHEMA.TABLE1 FROM '${path}/TABLE1.tsv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '\"'" \
  -c "truncate table SCHEMA.TABLE2;" \
  -c "\\copy SCHEMA.TABLE2 FROM '${path}/TABLE2.tsv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '\"'" \
  ${dbname} > ${log_file} 2>> ${log_file}
```

Comment: So ... where's the code in which you attempt to solve this, and what's the problem with that code? Please edit your question to include your attempt, any errors you're getting, or a detailed description of the unexpected behaviour you're seeing. If you're unable to create a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then at least give us the results you need help to interpret.

Comment: ok, i have eddited the question. Simple to say, i need to include file `sql.sql` in script but iserting it with variable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
sql=$(cat sql.sql)
```

Will put contents of "sql.sql" into this variable **$sql** but won't evaluate any variables inside it. The right way to do this is to use a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells), instead. But since I figure out you want to keep your script, a simple solution would be:

```
sql=$(cat sql.sql | sed -e 's@${path}@'"${path}"'@')
```

This is simple running sed to substitute the contents of **"${path}"** into the contents of shell variable of the same name. But anyway consider using heredocs, because your "sql" file is obviously not SQL at all.

Answer (score 1):

As advised, the HEREDOC is the best option and then simple parameter substitution can be done:

```
. properties

sql=$(cat sql.sql)

${psql_path}/psql <<-EOF
  -X
  --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on
  --set AUTOCOMMIT=on
  --echo-all
  ${sql//\$\{path\}/$path}
  ${dbname} > ${log_file} 2>> ${log_file}
EOF
```

Notice too that the line extensions are no longer required either.  You should be able to remove them from sql.sql file as well